# How to get solution file's Location

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to Copy file from my project Location to local Disk[i.e. on "D" drive]

My Solution Name --> CoffeeShop
I add existing item to my solution--FileName--Logo.JPG

I Just want to copy this Logo.JPG file from my project/solution location to Local D Disk.

I have an Idea about File.Copy() method.

But how i can set location of Logo.JPG file as from Location.

e.g.

```
string solutionFileLocation = [how I can get this location?]
string to_Location= @"D:\";

File.Copy(solutionFileLocation,to_Location);
```

Comment: Use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); to get the Current directory.So string solutionFileLocation=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Comment: @Joseph: negative.  the current directory is user-settable.

Comment: @Joseph: Do you want the solution directory (where the .sln file lives)? Or the location of the PNG file?  If the PNG, then is it copied to the output directory on compile?

Answer (score 4):

You should declare `using System.IO` and can get your solution path this way:

```
 var projectPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)));
```

Or if you need to check it only within VisualStudio:

```
var projectPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String solutionPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(0, Environment.CurrentDirectory.IndexOf("bin"));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really clean! With the newer range syntax you could do: `string solnRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()[..Environment.CurrentDirectory.IndexOf("bin")];`

Answer (score -6):

```
System.IO.File.Copy("source", "destination");
```

More details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx